# Invisible Installation (want to delete)

Tags: magento-1.9, installation

Recently we installed an extension that was not fully installed due to underprivileged write permissions. When we try to uninstall it through package manager, the extension is not appearing, and instead there is a small area under one of the Channel's that's empty. How would I go about deleting this extension if it was written to any directory or the database? Would I have to reinstall and uninstall? As well, could an incomplete install cause any issues to the server?